# Determining length in an array in Java (beginner)

Tags: java, arrays, string-length

I'm working with constructors and arrays, but I don't get why I cannot determine the length in this code:

```
public class tests3 {
  public static void main (String[] args){      
    Person[] pers = { new Person("10/05/1995", 5),
                      new Person("15/02/1993", 2),
                      new Person("20/11/1999"),
                      new Person("25/02/1980", 8),
                      new Person("30/01/1996", 3)
    };
    int nbElem = pers.lenght;

    System.out.printf("%d", nbElem);
  }
}
```

Comment: you misspelled length

Comment: `pers.length` and not `pers.lenght`

Comment: I feel so stupid now, I've just realized. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo. It is *pers.leng**th*** instead of *pers.lenght.